# Can I get name / reference to specialization value inside template specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

My code:

```
enum class list{one, two};
template <list T> class Base;
template <> class Base <list::one>{
    A a{list::one};
    B b{list::one};
    C c{list::one};
};
template <> class Base <list::two>{
    B b{list::two};
    C c{list::two};
    D d{list::two};
};
```

But I would like to avoid duplicating code, and use reference to specialization value, like this:

```
template <> class Base <list::one>{
    A a{T};
    B b{T};
    C c{T};
};
template <> class Base <list::two>{
    B b{T};
    C c{T};
    D d{T};
};
```

I can make sludge temporary variable, but does not look good too:

```
template <> class Base <list::one>{
    list T = list::one;
    A a{T};
    B b{T};
    C c{T};
};
```

Is there are any way to get reference to template specialization value?

Comment: I'm afraid making the variable is the only option. Just make sure you add `static constexpr` to it so is will behave the same way as the template parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following example I'm using SFINAE to make `T` available in the definition of `Base`. Specifically I have done the following:

- added one dummy type parameter to the primary template,
- made the two specialization partial by *not* specifying the parameter `T` (and specifying the second dummy type parameter),
- specified the second dummy type parameter enforcing that `T` is equal to `list::one` and `list::two` in the two specializations, via `std::enable_if_t`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class list{one, two};

// to make the code compile
class A { public: A(list) {} };
class B { public: B(list) {} };
class C { public: C(list) {} };
class D { public: D(list) {} };

// primary template (second param's sole purpose is to allow partial spec.)
template <list T, typename = void>
class Base;

// partial specialization #1
template <list T>
class Base <T, std::enable_if_t<T == list::one>>{
    A a{T};
    B b{T};
    C c{T};
  public:
    Base() { std::cout << "list::one\n"; }
};

// partial specialization #2
template <list T>
class Base <T, std::enable_if_t<T == list::two>>{
    B b{T};
    C c{T};
    D d{T};
  public:
    Base() { std::cout << "list::two\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Base<list::one> o;
    Base<list::two> t;
}
```

This is a pretty standard way of using taking advantage of SFINAE via `std::enable_if`. Similar examples can be found on [cppreference page on `std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), where the last example (the one with the first comment `// primary template`) resambles the code above.